# how to ask for username and password on lan computer when a user opens a web browser first time

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04

I have made database of 10 users and password. Now I want to prompt a dialog box on lan computer in which they have to enter username and password given by me whenever they open browser every time for accessing internet.
How can I do so?
I have also installed a squid proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/Mysql (assuming you have a MySQL database).

Answer (score 1):

You can use just basic username and password authentication. Since you are only talking about 10 users.

https://nodevine.com/library/messing-with-http-headers-in-squid-2-6-and-3-0-for-high-anonymity-in-centos-and-ubuntu